# mPDF PHP - Specific footnotes per page

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I use this https://mpdf.github.io to create a pdf.

Actually, the problem is :

I have a html code, with tags corresponding at a footnote. I would like a automatic creation of footnote in the footer when I have this tag in the html code.

Example :

```
$html = '
Quis enim aut eum diligat quem metuat, aut eum a quo se metui putet? Coluntur tamen simulatione dumtaxat ad tempus. 
Quod si forte, ut fit plerumque, ceciderunt, tum intellegitur quam fuerint inopes amicorum<sup>1</sup>.
```

[breakline automaticly by mpdf]

```
Quod Tarquinium dixisse ferunt, tum exsulantem se intellexisse quos fidos amicos habuisset, quos infidos<sup>2</sup>.
Cum iam neutris gratiam referre posset<sup>3</sup>. '
```

Output :

page 1 :

Quis enim aut eum diligat quem metuat, aut eum a quo se metui putet? Coluntur tamen simulatione dumtaxat ad tempus. 
Quod si forte, ut fit plerumque, ceciderunt, tum intellegitur quam fuerint inopes amicorum<sup>1</sup>

---

[footer empty]

page2 :

Quod Tarquinium dixisse ferunt, tum exsulantem se intellexisse quos fidos amicos habuisset, quos infidos<sup>2</sup>.
Cum iam neutris gratiam referre posset<sup>3</sup>.

---

[footer empty]

I try to do this : 
an insert before the tag  with this tag

```
<htmlpagefooter name="footer_page'.$mpdf->page.'">
1 : description footnote 1
</htmlpagefooter>
```

and

```
<sethtmlpagefooter name="footer_page_'. $mpdf->page .'" value="-1" />
```

to don't show on the next pages

But two problems :

For mpdf, we must

> - writes the footer for the current page
> - starts the new page

so if set the footer step by step, we can create somes inconsistencies because when we set the footer, if we modify the footer => we modify the space for the text, and therefore the size will be smaller and the part of text that contains the  tag can go on the other page.

- I can't set many times the footer for one page, I we have many times a htmlpagefooter  tag with the same name more than 1 time in the html code, mpdf take only the last tag.

so for example:

```
 <htmlpagefooter name="footer_page'.$mpdf->page.'">
    1 : description footnote 1
    </htmlpagefooter>
...
 <htmlpagefooter name="footer_page'.$mpdf->page.'">
    2 : description footnote 2
    </htmlpagefooter>
```

Output :

---

2 : description footnote 2

Sample.php :

```
//Need mpdf library
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('Auxerunt<sup date-note="text 1 ">1</sup> haec vulgi sordidioris audaciam, quod cum ingravesceret penuria commeatuum, famis et furoris inpulsu Eubuli cuiusdam inter suos clari domum ambitiosam ignibus subditis inflammavit rectoremque ut sibi iudicio imperiali addictum calcibus incessens et pugnis conculcans seminecem laniatu miserando discerpsit. post cuius lacrimosum interitum in unius exitio quisque imaginem periculi sui considerans documento recenti similia formidabat.Unde Rufinus ea tempestate praefectus praetorio ad discrimen trusus est ultimum. ire enim ipse compellebatur ad militem, quem exagitabat inopia simul et feritas, et alioqui coalito more in ordinarias dignitates asperum semper et saevum, ut satisfaceret atque monstraret, quam ob causam annonae convectio sit impedita.Illud autem non dubitatur quod cum esset aliquando virtutum omnium domicilium Roma, ingenuos advenas plerique nobilium, ut Homerici bacarum suavitate Lotophagi, humanitatis multiformibus officiis retentabant.Pandente itaque viam fatorum sorte tristissima, qua praestitutum erat eum vita et imperio spoliari, itineribus interiectis permutatione iumentorum emensis venit Petobionem oppidum Noricorum, ubi reseratae sunt insidiarum latebrae omnes, et Barbatio repente apparuit comes, qui sub eo domesticis praefuit, cum Apodemio agente in rebus milites ducens, quos beneficiis suis oppigneratos elegerat imperator certus nec praemiis nec miseratione ulla posse deflecti.Novo denique perniciosoque exemplo idem Gallus ausus est inire flagitium grave, quod Romae cum ultimo dedecore temptasse aliquando dicitur Gallienus, et adhibitis paucis clam ferro succinctis vesperi per tabernas palabatur et conpita quaeritando Graeco sermone, cuius erat inpendio gnarus, quid de Caesare quisque sentiret. et haec confidenter agebat in urbe ubi pernoctantium luminum claritudo dierum solet imitari fulgorem. postremo agnitus saepe iamque, si prodisset, conspicuum se fore contemplans, non nisi luce palam egrediens ad agenda quae putabat seria cernebatur. et haec quidem medullitus multis gementibus agebantur.Tempore quo primis auspiciis in mundanum fulgorem surgeret victura dum erunt homines Roma, ut augeretur sublimibus incrementis, foedere pacis aeternae Virtus convenit atque Fortuna plerumque dissidentes, quarum si altera defuisset, ad perfectam non venerat summitatem.Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt, sed adversando iurgandoque cum parum congrueret, eum ad rabiem potius evibrabat, Augustum actus eius exaggerando creberrime docens, idque, incertum qua mente, ne lateret adfectans. quibus mox Caesar acrius efferatus, velut contumaciae quoddam vexillum altius erigens, sine respectu salutis alienae vel suae ad vertenda opposita instar rapidi fluminis irrevocabili impetu ferebatur.Et quoniam inedia gravi adflictabantur, locum petivere Paleas nomine, vergentem in mare, valido muro firmatum, ubi conduntur nunc usque commeatus distribui militibus omne latus Isauriae defendentibus adsueti. circumstetere igitur hoc munimentum per triduum et trinoctium et cum neque adclivitas ipsa sine discrimine adiri letali, nec cuniculis quicquam geri posset, nec procederet ullum obsidionale commentum, maesti excedunt postrema vi subigente maiora viribus adgressuri.Nec piget dicere avide magis hanc insulam populum Romanum invasisse quam iuste. Ptolomaeo enim rege foederato nobis et socio ob aerarii nostri angustias iusso sine ulla culpa proscribi ideoque hausto veneno voluntaria morte deleto et tributaria facta est et velut hostiles eius exuviae classi inpositae in urbem advectae sunt per Catonem, nunc repetetur ordo gestorum.Altera sententia est, quae definit amicitiam paribus officiis ac voluntatibus. Hoc quidem est nimis exigue et exiliter ad calculos vocare amicitiam, ut par sit ratio acceptorum et datorum. Divitior mihi et affluentior videtur esse vera amicitia nec observare restricte, ne plus reddat quam acceperit; neque enim verendum est, ne quid excidat, aut ne quid in terram defluat, aut ne plus aequo quid in amicitiam congeratur Fieri, inquam, Triari, nullo pacto potest, ut non dicas, quid non probes eius, a quo dissentias. quid enim me prohiberet Epicureum esse, si probarem, quae ille diceret? cum praesertim illa perdiscere ludus esset. Quam ob rem dissentientium inter se reprehensiones non sunt vituperandae, maledicta, contumeliae, tum iracundiae, contentiones concertationesque in disputando pertinaces indignae philosophia mihi videri solent.Erat autem diritatis eius hoc quoque indicium nec obscurum nec latens, quod ludicris cruentis delectabatur et in circo sex vel septem aliquotiens vetitis certaminibus pugilum vicissim se concidentium perfusorumque sanguine specie<sup date-note="text 2 ">2</sup> ut lucratus ingentia laetabatur.Isdem diebus Apollinaris Domitiani gener, paulo ante agens palatii Caesaris curam, ad Mesopotamiam missus a socero per militares numeros immodice scrutabatur, an quaedam altiora meditantis iam Galli secreta susceperint scripta, qui conpertis Antiochiae gestis per minorem Armeniam lapsus Constantinopolim petit exindeque per protectores retractus artissime tenebatur.Horum adventum praedocti speculationibus fidis rectores militum tessera data sollemni armatos omnes celeri eduxere procursu et agiliter praeterito Calycadni fluminis ponte, cuius undarum magnitudo murorum adluit turres, in speciem locavere pugnandi. neque tamen exiluit quisquam nec permissus est congredi. formidabatur enim flagrans vesania manus et superior numero et ruitura sine respectu salutis in ferrum.Et Epigonus quidem amictu tenus philosophus, ut apparuit, prece frustra temptata, sulcatis lateribus mortisque metu admoto turpi confessione cogitatorum socium, quae nulla erant, fuisse firmavit cum nec vidisset quicquam nec audisset penitus expers forensium rerum; Eusebius vero obiecta fidentius negans, suspensus in eodem gradu constantiae stetit latrocinium illud esse, non iudicium clamans.Orientis vero limes in longum protentus et rectum ab Euphratis fluminis ripis ad usque supercilia porrigitur Nili, laeva Saracenis conterminans gentibus, dextra pelagi fragoribus patens, quam plagam Nicator Seleucus occupatam auxit magnum in modum, cum post Alexandri Macedonis obitum successorio iure teneret regna Persidis, efficaciae inpetrabilis rex, ut indicat cognomentum.Sin autem ad adulescentiam perduxissent, dirimi tamen interdum contentione vel uxoriae condicionis vel commodi alicuius, quod idem adipisci uterque non posset. Quod si qui longius in amicitia provecti essent, tamen saepe labefactari, si in honoris contentionem incidissent; pestem enim nullam maiorem esse amicitiis quam in plerisque pecuniae cupiditatem, in optimis quibusque honoris certamen et gloriae; ex quo inimicitias maximas saepe inter amicissimos exstitisse.Fieri, inquam, Triari, nullo pacto potest, ut non dicas, quid non probes eius, a quo dissentias. quid enim me prohiberet Epicureum esse, si probarem, quae ille diceret? cum praesertim illa perdiscere ludus esset. Quam ob rem dissentientium inter se reprehensiones non sunt vituperandae, maledicta, contumeliae, tum iracundiae, contentiones concertationesque in disputando pertinaces indignae philosophia mihi videri solent.Principium autem unde latius se funditabat, emersit ex negotio tali. Chilo ex vicario et coniux eius Maxima nomine, questi apud Olybrium ea tempestate urbi praefectum, vitamque suam venenis petitam adseverantes inpetrarunt ut hi, quos suspectati sunt, ilico rapti conpingerentur in vincula, organarius Sericus et Asbolius palaestrita et aruspex Campensis.Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt, sed adversando iurgandoque cum parum congrueret, eum ad rabiem potius evibrabat, Augustum actus eius exaggerando creberrime docens, idque, incertum qua mente, ne lateret adfectans. quibus mox Caesar acrius efferatus, velut contumaciae quoddam vexillum altius erigens, sine respectu salutis alienae vel suae ad vertenda opposita instar rapidi fluminis irrevocabili impetu<sup date-note="text 3 ">3</sup> ferebatur<sup date-note="text 4 ">4<sup>.');
    return $mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: Can you share a full working example that triggers your problem?

Comment: Can you add sample php file to recreate the issue?

Comment: Hi NicoHaase and Tarun Lalwani, I add an example Sample.php in my post

Comment: i updated my answer and i hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

as it says in the documentation [here](https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/method-2.html)
you need to add the footer to the page before adding new page to the document

> Changing Header/Footer during the document
>   This is where RUNTIME headers/footers get much more clumsy to use. When a new page is added to the document (e.g. using AddPage() or `<pagebreak>`) mPDF does the following:
>
> - writes the footer for the current page
> - starts the new page
> - writes the header for the new page
>
> Therefore to use any RUNTIME method you need to:
>
> - change the header before the page-break
> - change the footer after the page-break

```php
<?php
// First ensure that you are on an Even page
$mpdf->AddPage('','E');

// Then set the headers for the next page before you add the page
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('
<div style="text-align: right; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt;">
    Chapter 2
</div>','O');
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt;">
    Chapter 2
</div>','E');

$mpdf->AddPage();

$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('
<div style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold; font-size: 8pt; font-style: italic;">
    Chapter 2
</div>','O');
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('
<div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 8pt; font-style: italic;">
    Chapter 2
</div>','E');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('Rest of the document');

$mpdf->Output();
```

## an Update for updated question:

to my understanding your issue is that some pages require footers and others don't and you have an issue with footers not showing up

as for your footers that need to be updated regularly this class would solve this problem and you can alter it to your needs

```php
Class MyCustomFooter
{
    protected $footerId;
    protected $footer;

    public function __construct($footer = null)
    {
        $this->footerId = $this->uid('footer_');
        $this->setFooter($footer);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->footer;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->footerId;
    }

    public function setFooter($footer = null)
    {
        $this->footer = is_string($footer) ? $footer : '';
    }

    public function addFooter($text = '')
    {
        $this->footer .= $text;
    }

    public function uid($prefix = '',$length = 5)
    {
        $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        $max = strlen($characters) - 1;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $prefix .= $characters[mt_rand(0, $max)];
        }
        return $prefix;
    }
}
```

i hope this would solve your issue

```php
// using "mpdf/mpdf": "^7.0" on php:5.6
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$mpdf->AddPage();

$mpdf->WriteHTML('Auxerunt<sup date-note="text 1 ">1</sup> haec vulgi sordidioris audaciam, quod cum ingravesceret penuria commeatuum, famis et furoris inpulsu Eubuli cuiusdam inter suos clari domum ambitiosam ignibus subditis inflammavit rectoremque ut sibi iudicio imperiali addictum calcibus incessens et pugnis conculcans seminecem laniatu miserando discerpsit. post cuius lacrimosum interitum in unius exitio quisque imaginem periculi sui considerans documento recenti similia formidabat.Unde Rufinus ea tempestate praefectus praetorio ad discrimen trusus est ultimum. ire enim ipse compellebatur ad militem, quem exagitabat inopia simul et feritas, et alioqui coalito more in ordinarias dignitates asperum semper et saevum, ut satisfaceret atque monstraret, quam ob causam annonae convectio sit impedita.Illud autem non dubitatur quod cum esset aliquando virtutum omnium domicilium Roma, ingenuos advenas plerique nobilium, ut Homerici bacarum suavitate Lotophagi, humanitatis multiformibus officiis retentabant.Pandente itaque viam fatorum sorte tristissima, qua praestitutum erat eum vita et imperio spoliari, itineribus interiectis permutatione iumentorum emensis venit Petobionem oppidum Noricorum, ubi reseratae sunt insidiarum latebrae omnes, et Barbatio repente apparuit comes, qui sub eo domesticis praefuit, cum Apodemio agente in rebus milites ducens, quos beneficiis suis oppigneratos elegerat imperator certus nec praemiis nec miseratione ulla posse deflecti.Novo denique perniciosoque exemplo idem Gallus ausus est inire flagitium grave, quod Romae cum ultimo dedecore temptasse aliquando dicitur Gallienus, et adhibitis paucis clam ferro succinctis vesperi per tabernas palabatur et conpita quaeritando Graeco sermone, cuius erat inpendio gnarus, quid de Caesare quisque sentiret. et haec confidenter agebat in urbe ubi pernoctantium luminum claritudo dierum solet imitari fulgorem. postremo agnitus saepe iamque, si prodisset, conspicuum se fore contemplans, non nisi luce palam egrediens ad agenda quae putabat seria cernebatur. et haec quidem medullitus multis gementibus agebantur.Tempore quo primis auspiciis in mundanum fulgorem surgeret victura dum erunt homines Roma, ut augeretur sublimibus incrementis, foedere pacis aeternae Virtus convenit atque Fortuna plerumque dissidentes, quarum si altera defuisset, ad perfectam non venerat summitatem.Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt, sed adversando iurgandoque cum parum congrueret, eum ad rabiem potius evibrabat, Augustum actus eius exaggerando creberrime docens, idque, incertum qua mente, ne lateret adfectans. quibus mox Caesar acrius efferatus, velut contumaciae quoddam vexillum altius erigens, sine respectu salutis alienae vel suae ad vertenda opposita instar rapidi fluminis irrevocabili impetu ferebatur.Et quoniam inedia gravi adflictabantur, locum petivere Paleas nomine, vergentem in mare, valido muro firmatum, ubi conduntur nunc usque commeatus distribui militibus omne latus Isauriae defendentibus adsueti. circumstetere igitur hoc munimentum per triduum et trinoctium et cum neque adclivitas ipsa sine discrimine adiri letali, nec cuniculis quicquam geri posset, nec procederet ullum obsidionale commentum, maesti excedunt postrema vi subigente maiora viribus adgressuri.Nec piget dicere avide magis hanc insulam populum Romanum invasisse quam iuste. Ptolomaeo enim rege foederato nobis et socio ob aerarii nostri angustias iusso sine ulla culpa proscribi ideoque hausto veneno voluntaria morte deleto et tributaria facta est et velut hostiles eius exuviae classi inpositae in urbem advectae sunt per Catonem, nunc repetetur ordo gestorum.Altera sententia est, quae definit amicitiam paribus officiis ac voluntatibus. Hoc quidem est nimis exigue et exiliter ad calculos vocare amicitiam, ut par sit ratio acceptorum et datorum. Divitior mihi et affluentior videtur esse vera amicitia nec observare restricte, ne plus reddat quam acceperit; neque enim verendum est, ne quid excidat, aut ne quid in terram defluat, aut ne plus aequo quid in amicitiam congeratur Fieri, inquam, Triari, nullo pacto potest, ut non dicas, quid non probes eius, a quo dissentias. quid enim me prohiberet Epicureum esse, si probarem, quae ille diceret? cum praesertim illa perdiscere ludus esset. Quam ob rem dissentientium inter se reprehensiones non sunt vituperandae, maledicta, contumeliae, tum iracundiae, contentiones concertationesque in disputando pertinaces indignae philosophia mihi videri solent.Erat autem diritatis eius hoc quoque indicium nec obscurum nec latens, quod ludicris cruentis delectabatur et in circo sex vel septem aliquotiens vetitis certaminibus pugilum vicissim se concidentium perfusorumque sanguine specie<sup date-note="text 2 ">2</sup> ut lucratus ingentia laetabatur.Isdem diebus Apollinaris Domitiani gener, paulo ante agens palatii Caesaris curam, ad Mesopotamiam missus a socero per militares numeros immodice scrutabatur, an quaedam altiora meditantis iam Galli secreta susceperint scripta, qui conpertis Antiochiae gestis per minorem Armeniam lapsus Constantinopolim petit exindeque per protectores retractus artissime tenebatur.Horum adventum praedocti speculationibus fidis rectores militum tessera data sollemni armatos omnes celeri eduxere procursu et agiliter praeterito Calycadni fluminis ponte, cuius undarum magnitudo murorum adluit turres, in speciem locavere pugnandi. neque tamen exiluit quisquam nec permissus est congredi. formidabatur enim flagrans vesania manus et superior numero et ruitura sine respectu salutis in ferrum.Et Epigonus quidem amictu tenus philosophus, ut apparuit, prece frustra temptata, sulcatis lateribus mortisque metu admoto turpi confessione cogitatorum socium, quae nulla erant, fuisse firmavit cum nec vidisset quicquam nec audisset penitus expers forensium rerum; Eusebius vero obiecta fidentius negans, suspensus in eodem gradu constantiae stetit latrocinium illud esse, non iudicium clamans.Orientis vero limes in longum protentus et rectum ab Euphratis fluminis ripis ad usque supercilia porrigitur Nili, laeva Saracenis conterminans gentibus, dextra pelagi fragoribus patens, quam plagam Nicator Seleucus occupatam auxit magnum in modum, cum post Alexandri Macedonis obitum successorio iure teneret regna Persidis, efficaciae inpetrabilis rex, ut indicat cognomentum.Sin autem ad adulescentiam perduxissent, dirimi tamen interdum contentione vel uxoriae condicionis vel commodi alicuius, quod idem adipisci uterque non posset. Quod si qui longius in amicitia provecti essent, tamen saepe labefactari, si in honoris contentionem incidissent; pestem enim nullam maiorem esse amicitiis quam in plerisque pecuniae cupiditatem, in optimis quibusque honoris certamen et gloriae; ex quo inimicitias maximas saepe inter amicissimos exstitisse.Fieri, inquam, Triari, nullo pacto potest, ut non dicas, quid non probes eius, a quo dissentias. quid enim me prohiberet Epicureum esse, si probarem, quae ille diceret? cum praesertim illa perdiscere ludus esset. Quam ob rem dissentientium inter se reprehensiones non sunt vituperandae, maledicta, contumeliae, tum iracundiae, contentiones concertationesque in disputando pertinaces indignae philosophia mihi videri solent.Principium autem unde latius se funditabat, emersit ex negotio tali. Chilo ex vicario et coniux eius Maxima nomine, questi apud Olybrium ea tempestate urbi praefectum, vitamque suam venenis petitam adseverantes inpetrarunt ut hi, quos suspectati sunt, ilico rapti conpingerentur in vincula, organarius Sericus et Asbolius palaestrita et aruspex Campensis.Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt, sed adversando iurgandoque cum parum congrueret, eum ad rabiem potius evibrabat, Augustum actus eius exaggerando creberrime docens, idque, incertum qua mente, ne lateret adfectans. quibus mox Caesar acrius efferatus, velut contumaciae quoddam vexillum altius erigens, sine respectu salutis alienae vel suae ad vertenda opposita instar rapidi fluminis irrevocabili impetu<sup date-note="text 3 ">3</sup> ferebatur<sup date-note="text 4 ">4<sup>.');

$footer1 = new MyCustomFooter('1 : description footnote 1');

$mpdf->DefHTMLFooterByName($footer1->getId(), $footer1);

$footer1->addFooter('<br>2 : description footnote 2');

$mpdf->SetHTMLFooterByName($footer1->getId());

// stop using footers
$mpdf->AddPageByArray([
    'odd-footer-value' => '-1'
]);

$mpdf->WriteHTML('Auxerunt<sup date-note="text 1 ">1</sup> haec vulgi sordidioris audaciam, quod cum ingravesceret penuria commeatuum, famis et furoris inpulsu Eubuli cuiusdam inter suos clari domum ambitiosam ignibus subditis inflammavit rectoremque ut sibi iudicio imperiali addictum calcibus incessens et pugnis conculcans seminecem laniatu miserando discerpsit. post cuius lacrimosum interitum in unius exitio quisque imaginem periculi sui considerans documento recenti similia formidabat.Unde Rufinus ea tempestate praefectus praetorio ad discrimen trusus est ultimum. ire enim ipse compellebatur ad militem, quem exagitabat inopia simul et feritas, et alioqui coalito more in ordinarias dignitates asperum semper et saevum, ut satisfaceret atque monstraret, quam ob causam annonae convectio sit impedita.Illud autem non dubitatur quod cum esset aliquando virtutum omnium domicilium Roma, ingenuos advenas plerique nobilium, ut Homerici bacarum suavitate Lotophagi, humanitatis multiformibus officiis retentabant.Pandente itaque viam fatorum sorte tristissima, qua praestitutum erat eum vita et imperio spoliari, itineribus interiectis permutatione iumentorum emensis venit Petobionem oppidum Noricorum, ubi reseratae sunt insidiarum latebrae omnes, et Barbatio repente apparuit comes, qui sub eo domesticis praefuit, cum Apodemio agente in rebus milites ducens, quos beneficiis suis oppigneratos elegerat imperator certus nec praemiis nec miseratione ulla posse deflecti.Novo denique perniciosoque exemplo idem Gallus ausus est inire flagitium grave, quod Romae cum ultimo dedecore temptasse aliquando dicitur Gallienus, et adhibitis paucis clam ferro succinctis vesperi per tabernas palabatur et conpita quaeritando Graeco sermone, cuius erat inpendio gnarus, quid de Caesare quisque sentiret. et haec confidenter agebat in urbe ubi pernoctantium luminum claritudo dierum solet imitari fulgorem. postremo agnitus saepe iamque, si prodisset, conspicuum se fore contemplans, non nisi luce palam egrediens ad agenda quae putabat seria cernebatur. et haec quidem medullitus multis gementibus agebantur.Tempore quo primis auspiciis in mundanum fulgorem surgeret victura dum erunt homines Roma, ut augeretur sublimibus incrementis, foedere pacis aeternae Virtus convenit atque Fortuna plerumque dissidentes, quarum si altera defuisset, ad perfectam non venerat summitatem.Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt, sed adversando iurgandoque cum parum congrueret, eum ad rabiem potius evibrabat, Augustum actus eius exaggerando creberrime docens, idque, incertum qua mente, ne lateret adfectans. quibus mox Caesar acrius efferatus, velut contumaciae quoddam vexillum altius erigens, sine respectu salutis alienae vel suae ad vertenda opposita instar rapidi fluminis irrevocabili impetu ferebatur.Et quoniam inedia gravi adflictabantur, locum petivere Paleas nomine, vergentem in mare, valido muro firmatum, ubi conduntur nunc usque commeatus distribui militibus omne latus Isauriae defendentibus adsueti. circumstetere igitur hoc munimentum per triduum et trinoctium et cum neque adclivitas ipsa sine discrimine adiri letali, nec cuniculis quicquam geri posset, nec procederet ullum obsidionale commentum, maesti excedunt postrema vi subigente maiora viribus adgressuri.Nec piget dicere avide magis hanc insulam populum Romanum invasisse quam iuste. Ptolomaeo enim rege foederato nobis et socio ob aerarii nostri angustias iusso sine ulla culpa proscribi ideoque hausto veneno voluntaria morte deleto et tributaria facta est et velut hostiles eius exuviae classi inpositae in urbem advectae sunt per Catonem, nunc repetetur ordo gestorum.Altera sententia est, quae definit amicitiam paribus officiis ac voluntatibus. Hoc quidem est nimis exigue et exiliter ad calculos vocare amicitiam, ut par sit ratio acceptorum et datorum. Divitior mihi et affluentior videtur esse vera amicitia nec observare restricte, ne plus reddat quam acceperit; neque enim verendum est, ne quid excidat, aut ne quid in terram defluat, aut ne plus aequo quid in amicitiam congeratur Fieri, inquam, Triari, nullo pacto potest, ut non dicas, quid non probes eius, a quo dissentias. quid enim me prohiberet Epicureum esse, si probarem, quae ille diceret? cum praesertim illa perdiscere ludus esset. Quam ob rem dissentientium inter se reprehensiones non sunt vituperandae, maledicta, contumeliae, tum iracundiae, contentiones concertationesque in disputando pertinaces indignae philosophia mihi videri solent.Erat autem diritatis eius hoc quoque indicium nec obscurum nec latens, quod ludicris cruentis delectabatur et in circo sex vel septem aliquotiens vetitis certaminibus pugilum vicissim se concidentium perfusorumque sanguine specie<sup date-note="text 2 ">2</sup> ut lucratus ingentia laetabatur.Isdem diebus Apollinaris Domitiani gener, paulo ante agens palatii Caesaris curam, ad Mesopotamiam missus a socero per militares numeros immodice scrutabatur, an quaedam altiora meditantis iam Galli secreta susceperint scripta, qui conpertis Antiochiae gestis per minorem Armeniam lapsus Constantinopolim petit exindeque per protectores retractus artissime tenebatur.Horum adventum praedocti speculationibus fidis rectores militum tessera data sollemni armatos omnes celeri eduxere procursu et agiliter praeterito Calycadni fluminis ponte, cuius undarum magnitudo murorum adluit turres, in speciem locavere pugnandi. neque tamen exiluit quisquam nec permissus est congredi. formidabatur enim flagrans vesania manus et superior numero et ruitura sine respectu salutis in ferrum.Et Epigonus quidem amictu tenus philosophus, ut apparuit, prece frustra temptata, sulcatis lateribus mortisque metu admoto turpi confessione cogitatorum socium, quae nulla erant, fuisse firmavit cum nec vidisset quicquam nec audisset penitus expers forensium rerum; Eusebius vero obiecta fidentius negans, suspensus in eodem gradu constantiae stetit latrocinium illud esse, non iudicium clamans.Orientis vero limes in longum protentus et rectum ab Euphratis fluminis ripis ad usque supercilia porrigitur Nili, laeva Saracenis conterminans gentibus, dextra pelagi fragoribus patens, quam plagam Nicator Seleucus occupatam auxit magnum in modum, cum post Alexandri Macedonis obitum successorio iure teneret regna Persidis, efficaciae inpetrabilis rex, ut indicat cognomentum.Sin autem ad adulescentiam perduxissent, dirimi tamen interdum contentione vel uxoriae condicionis vel commodi alicuius, quod idem adipisci uterque non posset. Quod si qui longius in amicitia provecti essent, tamen saepe labefactari, si in honoris contentionem incidissent; pestem enim nullam maiorem esse amicitiis quam in plerisque pecuniae cupiditatem, in optimis quibusque honoris certamen et gloriae; ex quo inimicitias maximas saepe inter amicissimos exstitisse.Fieri, inquam, Triari, nullo pacto potest, ut non dicas, quid non probes eius, a quo dissentias. quid enim me prohiberet Epicureum esse, si probarem, quae ille diceret? cum praesertim illa perdiscere ludus esset. Quam ob rem dissentientium inter se reprehensiones non sunt vituperandae, maledicta, contumeliae, tum iracundiae, contentiones concertationesque in disputando pertinaces indignae philosophia mihi videri solent.Principium autem unde latius se funditabat, emersit ex negotio tali. Chilo ex vicario et coniux eius Maxima nomine, questi apud Olybrium ea tempestate urbi praefectum, vitamque suam venenis petitam adseverantes inpetrarunt ut hi, quos suspectati sunt, ilico rapti conpingerentur in vincula, organarius Sericus et Asbolius palaestrita et aruspex Campensis.Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt, sed adversando iurgandoque cum parum congrueret, eum ad rabiem potius evibrabat, Augustum actus eius exaggerando creberrime docens, idque, incertum qua mente, ne lateret adfectans. quibus mox Caesar acrius efferatus, velut contumaciae quoddam vexillum altius erigens, sine respectu salutis alienae vel suae ad vertenda opposita instar rapidi fluminis irrevocabili impetu<sup date-note="text 3 ">3</sup> ferebatur<sup date-note="text 4 ">4<sup>.');

$mpdf->AddPage();

$footer2 = new MyCustomFooter('1 : another description footnote 1');

$mpdf->DefHTMLFooterByName($footer2->getId(), $footer2);

$footer2->addFooter('<br>2 : another description footnote 2');

$mpdf->SetHTMLFooterByName($footer2->getId());

$mpdf->WriteHTML('this is page 4 with new footer');

return $mpdf->Output();
```

[result pdf file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/buqvzwy0hdutasm/mpdf.pdf?dl=0)